# Meaning of “The Present tense would be syntactically best described as non-past”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, present-tense, syntax, terminology

I'm reading "Meaning and the English Verb" by Geoffrey Leech and in the paragraph §113 on page 71 he states the following:

§113:

> First, the ways of referring to the future dealt with in this chapter illustrate the point made in §5: that the Present Tense, from the semantic point of view as well as syntactically, would be best described as 'non-past'. We have seen that all these future-referring constructions are variations on the Present Tense, with the very minor exception of the future subordinate use of the Past (see §102c) - even including the 'non-past' modal auxiliaries will / shall, to which we turn again in the next chapter. In other words, the Present Tense, in a broad sense, encompasses both present and future domains of time.

§5:

> However, in English the major formal distinction of Present and Past tenses can be associated with two major TIME ZONES, 'past' and 'non-past', so that future time is subsumed under 'non-past'. This helps to explain why English, which does not have a Future tense as such, uses Present tense to express future time.

I know what he means by "from the semantic point of view", but I do not understand what he means by "syntactically" in this context.

**So what does it mean when he says that "The Present tense would be syntactically best described as 'non-past'"?**

Comment: Your "But it would be better described as:" examples are correct. So it looks like you understand the author's meaning. Do you still have a more specific question?

Comment: The terms "past" and "non-past" are not viable *semantic* categories in English (semantically our distinctions in respect to time are much more refined than that!) but simply a way of describing the absence of marked grammatical features—the same verb form can be used to refer to present-actual, present-usual, and future.

Comment: Please don't post the **[exact same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423921/meaning-of-the-present-tense-would-be-syntactically-best-described-as-non-past)** on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Syntax" (in general) refers to how a language is *structured*.  "Semantics" (in general) refers to what the words actually *mean*.  According to the author, since English has no formal "future tense" we can both syntactically and semantically divide expressions into either "past" or "non-past".

The author therefore argues that the present tense can be syntactically labelled "non-past tense", because English speakers can use the present tense to describe future events, e.g.:

> Tomorrow I **have** a dentist appointment.
>
> Next week I **go** to Europe.

Basically the author creates logical groupings, which I assume will be important to the next part of the argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. So by "The Present tense would be **syntactically (not semantically)** best described as 'non-past'" the author argues using the label "Non-past tense" instead of the label "Present tense" for the present tense (verb form)?

Comment: @Sinushyperbolikus  That's what he says.  I'm not familiar enough with linguistics to understand why something like "will have" or "will go" are **not** a *valid* future tense syntax, since these can only represent future actions.